# How to get values from an NSArray after applying filter to NSArrayController in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I'm learning bindings in cocoa. My ArrayController is bound to a tableview and a searchfield. data display and filtering is fine. 
These properties are in the mutableArray.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *displayName;
@property NSInteger entityID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *MemberStatus;
```

In the table, I'm displaying the 'displayName'. My main problem is, I need to select a row and run an webservice using 'entityID' of that selected member.

If I do not filter and select a row, I'm able to fetch the needed 'entityID' from the mutable array using selected row index.

```
[[[self.participantArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow] valueForKey:@"entityID"] integerValue]
```

Whenever I'm filtering, depending on the selected row index it is returning wrong values naturally. How do I get the correct fields? Please help. If my question is not clear, please mention what you need. 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table view is displaying the `arrangedObjects` of the array controller. So, you should index into that, too.

You will need an outlet to the array controller so that you can do something like:

```
[[[self.particpantsController.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:selectedRow] valueForKey:@"entityID"] integerValue]
```

(I'm actually not sure why you're using `-valueForKey:` here. The expression `[self.particpantsController.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:selectedRow]` gives you the object. If it has an `entityID` property, you can just call the getter on that object. If it's an `NSDictionary`, then you should prefer `-objectForKey:` over `-valueForKey:`. Well, actually, you should prefer creating a real model object class and using that rather than `NSDictionary`. Making dictionaries tends to work well in toy apps and prototyping, but quickly shows its limits.)